# Reverse Drilldown Reportbuilder 3

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have an expanded report and but the initial group +/- now works in reverse.  I know I need to change this but can not find where in ReportBuilder 3.0.  Can anyone advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up a drilldown, you need to specify the toggle item that controls the drilldown action (typically a textbox).

That toggle item will have an **InitialToggleState** property - change this from *False* to *True* or vice versa as required, and this will control whether **+** or **-** is displayed in the toggle item when the report is first loaded.

Update as required to match the initial state of the items being shown/hidden.

[image]

You can see this under **Properties** -> **Visibility** when the toggle item is selected (see right above). Make sure you have **View** -> **Properties** checked (see top above) to see this tab.

Comment: Hi there, yes its that initialtogglestate property that I can not find in Report Builder 3.0